# How to print n number of optional and required arguments with -h and align

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

**My Issue**

I'm using argparse module to parse input arguments. Where two-argument *Required arguments*
& *Optional arguments* groups are being used to maintain *Required arguments* at the first position then *Optional arguments*.

My first issue:

> Usage message does not contain all the switches.

```
usage: logger_parser.py [-h] -name Name
                                           -identification_number Id -email
                                           Email [-address]
                                           [-sex]
```

Second issue:

> Required arguments are not fully formatted with -h option

```
Required arguments:
  -name Name            Name.
  - identification_number 
                        Id.
  -email                Email.
```

Third issue:

> Optional argument group does not show all arguments it has, shows only 2 arguments, though I have four arguments.

```
Optional arguments:
  -address              Address.
  -sex                  Sex.
```

**Code**

The following is my sample code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Employee Enrollmeny."
  # add_help=False
)   

parser._action_groups.pop()
requiredArgument = parser.add_argument_group(
   'Required arguments'
)   
optionalArgument = parser.add_argument_group(
   'Optional arguments'
)   
requiredArgument.add_argument(
    '-name', 
    type=str, 
    required=True,
    help='Name.'
)   
requiredArgument.add_argument(
    '-identification_number',
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help='Id.'
)
requiredArgument.add_argument(
    '-email',
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help='Email.'
)
optionalArgument.add_argument(
    '-address',
    type=str,
    metavar='',
    help='Address.'
)      
optionalArgument.add_argument(
    '-sex',
    type=str,
    metavar='',
    help='Sex'
) 
optionalArgument.add_argument(
    '-age',
    type=str,
    metavar='',
    help='Age'
)  
optionalArgument.add_argument(
    '-h',
    type=str,
    action='help',
    metavar='',
    help='show this help message and exit'
)   
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.name)
```

**Output**

```
usage: logger_parser.py [-h] -name Name
                                           -identification_number Id -email
                                           Email [-address]
                                           [-sex]

Update employee info

Required arguments:
  -name Name            Name.
  - identification_number 
                        Id.
  -email                Email.

Optional arguments:
  -address              Address.
  -sex                  Sex.
```

**Expected Output**

```
usage: logger_parser.py [-h] -name Name
                                           -identification_number Id -email
                                           Email [-address]
                                           [-sex] [-age]

Update employee info.

Required arguments:
  -name Name               Name.
  - identification_number  Id.
  -email                   Email.

Optional arguments:
  -address                 Address.
  -sex                     Sex.
  -age                     Age
  -help                    show this help message and exit
```

Comment: The last `-h` definition shouldn't have a `type` parameter.  `-identification` needs a metavar  (might also shorten the flag to clean up the indentation.  Instead of `pop` the default group, you could change its title.

Comment: @hpaulj
The last -h definition, has parameter ```type=str```.

Comment: it shouldn't have `type`.  It doesn't take any arguments `nargs=0`. The other `type=str` are superfluous.

Comment: Alignment is a function window width and argument name length.  You might want to shorten `identification_number`.  The `HelpFormater` class also takes some indentation and width parameters. How to set or change those is more than what I can address now.